# Functions in javascript and scopes

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Here i have simplified my problem to this code. I need to build a table. I have 3 functions(one,two,three) that have specific functionality, and i have a main function that builds a table from the return of this 3 functions. However i don't fully understand how to finish this.

```
function foo(one,two,three){
    var result = "";
    for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
       result+= arguments[i](true);
       result+= arguments[i](false);
    }
    console.log(result);
}
 foo(one);
```

There could be 2 more functions, but in this case it doesn't matter i wrote only one. So the one() can accept 2 arguments(true or false) and

```
function one(arg){
    if(arg == true){
        this.result += "1-true";
    } else if(arg ==false){
        this.result += "1-false";
    }
    return this.result;
}
```

Comment: Why in `one()` function you use `this` to return result?

Comment: You can only use `this.result` if the function is a prototype method of an object. But you're not binding the function call to an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function, it won't inherit the scope from the calling code, so the property `this.result` in the `one` function won't be the same as the local variable `result` in the `foo` function.

Unless you call a function as a method of an object, the context of the function (`this`) will be the global `window` object. Inside the `one` function `this.result` will be the same as `window.result`. As the `window` object is the global context, you will create a global variable named `result`.

The variable `result` declared inside the `foo` function is local to that function, and it's separate from the global `result` variable. From the `one` function you can't even reach the `result` variable in `foo` function at all.

As the `one` function is using a global variable that is never assigned a value, it will contain `undefined` from the start. Adding `"1-true"` to it will convert `undefined` into the string `"undefined"` and the result is `"undefined1-true"`. In the next call to `one` the value in the global variable is still there, so it will add `"1-false"` to it, making it `"undefined1-true1false"`. As the `foo` function adds the values from the first and the second call to `one`, the result is `"undefined1-trueundefined1-true1-false"`.

If you would use the global variable in both functions so that they used the same variable (which is what it seems that you tried to do), you would get a different result. The `one` function would add `"1-true"` to the variable and then return the variable. The `foo` function would then add the returned value to the variable, making it `"1-true1-true"`. The next call to `one` would add `"1-false"` to the variable making it `"1-true1-true1-false"` and then return the value of the variable, which the `foo` function adds to the variable, making it `"1-true1-true1-false1-true1-true1-false"`.

Instead of adding to the variable in both functions, you should just return a string from the `one` function, and put the strings together in the `foo` function:

```
function foo(one,two,three) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i](true);
    result += arguments[i](false);
  }
  console.log(result);
}
foo(one);

function one(arg) {
  if(arg == true) {
    return "1-true";
  } else if (arg == false) {
    return "1-false";
  }
}
```

Note: Instead of using `if (arg == true)` you can just use `if (arg)`, and the `else if()` can just be an `else`:

```
function one(arg) {
  if(arg) {
    return "1-true";
  } else {
    return "1-false";
  }
}
```

You can also use the conditional operator to get the same result:

```
function one(arg) {
  return arg ? "1-true" : "1-false";
}
```

If you still want to use a variable in the `one` function, you don't need to use the `+=` operator as you only have one string. You can just assign the value:

```
function one(arg) {
  var result;
  if(arg) {
    result = "1-true";
  } else {
    result = "1-false";
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I considered your answer and figured solution to my problem.

Comment: can you please check out my new answers? Maybe you could help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change condition for function one:

```
var result = '';
if (arg) { .... } else { ... };
return ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions, considering all the answers above i figured out the solution.

```
function foo(one, two,three) {

//Vehicle parts
var vhcparts = {
    a: "cabin",
    b: "wheel",
    c: "body",
    d: "trail",
    e: "back",
    f: "doublewheel",
    g: "triplewheel",
    h: "fourwheel",
    i: "aftercabin",
    j: "bodybegin"
}
//Final image string  + 2chars, to add extra space at front and back;
var imageDescription = "aijbcccccccge" // obj.imageDescription;
imageDescription = "-" + imageDescription + "-";

//Iterate throught list of arguments to build specific line of TruckMainBoard
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += "<tr>";
    //Iterate throught image string to generate td and populate it
    for (var j=0;j<imageDescription.length;j++){
        // Verify if imageDescription string matches vhcparts(vehicle parts) array.
        for (var p in vhcparts){
            // var counter = 0;
            if(imageDescription[j] == p
                &&
                (imageDescription[j] == "a" ||
                    imageDescription[j] == "b" ||
                    imageDescription[j] == "f" ||
                    imageDescription[j] == "g" ||
                    imageDescription[j] == "h"
                    )
                )
            {
                result += arguments[i](true);
            }
            else if(imageDescription[j] == p)  {

                result += arguments[i](false);
            }
        }
    }
    result += "</tr>"
}
console.log(result);}

function one(arg){
var result = "";
if(arg){
    result += '<td><img src="images/';
    //result += vhcparts[p];
    result +='.png">';
    result +='</td>';
} else {
    console.log("nothing to print")
}
return result;
}


foo(one,two);
```

Comment: You have placed the `one` function inside the `foo` function, which means that it can access `vhcparts[p]`, but that also means that the call `foo(one, two)` won't be able to access the function `one`. You need to put the function `one` outside the `foo` function to be able to reach it, but that means that it no longer can access `vhcparts[p]` directly. You would need to pass it along in the call: `result += arguments[i](true, vhcparts[p]);` and add a parameter to the `one` function.

Comment: @Guffa: it worked, thanks, however would you recommend to use this kind of programm structure, or it would be better to create object and access it's methods? `Foo.prototype.one = function(){..}`

Comment: If you have a single object, then it doesn't make much difference. It would be more useful if you for example had one object instance for each vehicle part.